# Changing the interface language on the Input app (iPhone)

Tags: qgis, internationalization, input

A while ago, I downloaded the Input app for my iPhone (iOS 14.8). The interface language is set to an Asian language, and I can't figure out how to change it. I've tried to delete it and reinstall, but with no luck. I also have downloaded it on my iPad, and it works fine.

Is there anybody who've had the same problem and might have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely you have another language in your system. If you go to your Settings and remove the other language it should default to the system language:
https://github.com/lutraconsulting/input/issues/1417